# How to dynamically change a method arguments in Python

Tags: python, methods, dynamic, arguments, definition

Is it possible to dynamically add arguments to a Python method definition ?

I'm currently working on this piece of code:

```
def method(self):
    pass

method.__name__ = "print"
```

and I want to know if it's possible to change the method's definition dynamically, like i'm changing it's name, and for example add a string argument ?

Comment: And what's the purpose of changing the name?

Comment: Would using a dictionary in order to be able to pass as many or as little parameters be useful?

Comment: Use *args or **kwargs to get a custom len or arguments

Comment: @chepner Well I just wrote an empty function to explain but I have a list of functions to create dynamically in Python and all these functions will call another python method with the arguments stored in a list.

Comment: You can pass methods as arguments, so if it's possible that there are a finite and reasonable number of different methods you need, then just write them all out. Or put some branching inside the method to manage the number of possibilities?

Comment: Seems like you should be using higher-order functions, not dynamically changing functions.

Comment: I though about using the *args and **kwargs but then I need to find a way to check if the arguments are correct, for example the print function only takes a string, if the user passes an integer I want to be able to warn him about the wrong usage of the function.

Comment: There is also a function you can run called exec(), which will run a string variable as code, but you probably don't want to do this.   Edit:  and by probably, I mean you definitely don't want to do this.